# How can a subquery return a tuple instead of a value?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with a subquery used in a select statement in SQL Server. I have a table `corona` with columns `id, datekey, coronanewcases, coronadeaths`.

Note that `datekey` is an integer indicate date, for example 20200112 means January 12, 2020. Then I have to calculate accumulated `coronanewcases` and accumulated `coronanewcases`. Accumulation by `datekey_1` of field_1 is sum of field_1 in tuples have `datekey` happens before or equals `datekey_1` and in a same month of `datekey_1`.

For example: accumulation by 20200112 of `coronanewcases` is sum of `coronanewcases` for dates in January and happens before or equals January 12, 2020.

I want to write a query as following:

```
SELECT 
    corona.datekey, 
    (SELECT SUM(sub.coronanewcases), SUM(sub.coronadeaths) 
     FROM corona AS sub 
     WHERE sub.datekey BETWEEN (corona.datekey/100) * 100 + 1 
       AND ((corona.datekey / 100) * 100 + corona.datekey % 100)
FROM 
    corona
GROUP BY 
    corona.datekey;
```

I know this query is wrong for T-SQL, because subquery used in select can only returns a single value. But is there any way to make it return a tuple? I don't want to write as following because it is long and complex:

```
SELECT 
    corona.datekey, 
    (SELECT SUM(sub.coronanewcases)
     FROM corona AS sub 
     WHERE sub.datekey BETWEEN (corona.datekey/100)*100 + 1 
       AND ((corona.datekey/100)*100 + corona.datekey%100) AS [accumulation of coronanewcases], 
    (SELECT SUM(sub.coronadeaths)
     FROM corona AS sub 
     WHERE sub.datekey BETWEEN (corona.datekey/100)*100 + 1 
       AND ((corona.datekey/100)*100 + corona.datekey%100) AS [accumulation of coronadeaths]
FROM 
    corona
GROUP BY 
    corona.datekey;
```

I hope someone can help. Thank you!

Comment: you could use a CTE

Comment: or a window function sum e.g. `sum(column) over (partition by ...). Why did you use `int` for a `date`? That sounds like a bad idea. Sample data and expected results (in DDL/DML form) will make it much easier to assist you.

Comment: As an aside, if your table is already called 'corona' why prefix your column names with 'corona'? Just gives you more to type.

Comment: @Dale K: Your method solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: @Dale K ok. Use sum() over() can solve this ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution of Dale K, and it solved my problem. We will use `SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY)` as following:

```
SELECT T1.datekey, [Accumulation coronanewcases], [Accumulation coronadeaths]
FROM
(
    SELECT datekey
        , MAX([Accumulation coronanewcases]) AS [Accumulation coronanewcases]
        , MAX([Accumulation coronadeaths]) AS [Accumulation coronadeaths]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT (datekey/100) AS [monthkey], datekey
            , SUM(coronanewcases) OVER (PARTITION BY (datekey/100) ORDER BY datekey ASC) AS [Accumulation coronanewcases]
            , SUM(coronadeaths) OVER (PARTITION BY (datekey/100) ORDER BY datekey ASC) AS [Accumulation coronadeaths]
        FROM corona
    ) AS T
    GROUP BY datekey
)
```

With above solution, we don't need to get `SUM(coronanewcases)` and `SUM(coronadeaths)` by 2 different queries on a same table `'corona'`. We only get them from table `'corona'` in the unique query.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `CROSS APPLY` - it does allow you to essentially return a tuple from a sub-query but I don't know whether the logic works for you given the lack of sample data + expected results.

```
SELECT C.datekey, S.TotalNewCases, S.TotalDeaths
FROM @corona C
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT SUM(sub.coronanewcases) TotalNewCases, SUM(sub.coronadeaths) TotalDeaths
  FROM @corona AS sub
  WHERE sub.datekey BETWEEN (C.datekey/100)*100 + 1 AND ((C.datekey/100)*100 + C.datekey%100)
) S
GROUP BY C.datekey, S.TotalNewCases, S.TotalDeaths
```